# Joomla - Conditional Load of Plugin based on Menu Item

Tags: joomla1.5

Is it possible to load a System Plugin conditionally, based on menu items?

e.g. some pages in my site are conflicting with the Mootools Upgrade plugin, which is required for Kunena.  I want to only include the plugin on the Kunena pages.

Thanks
Geoff

Answer (score 0):

There is no native way of doing this.

To keep things the way they are now and not have conflicts in future updates -create a Plug-in that load last. It's job is to check [JDocument](http://docs.joomla.org/JDocument) and see script was loaded and if so Remove it from there if page is non Kunena or vise versa...
E.g. Disable the kunena plug-in, and in your plug-in check if page is Kunena... if so load that plug-in programmatically.